# How to set ID for Buttons in asp.net dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I wrote this code for set id for buttons by reading a field from db connected to sqldatasource,but the error say that I can set id like ID="btn1". but this is static. what should I do?

```
 <asp:Button ID='<%# Eval("num") %>'  runat="server" cssclass=btnd  OnClick="delete_kala"  />
```

### this code is in datalist connected to sqldatasource.

codes for reading data from db:

```
        <table class="cart-table">
        <tr>
        <td width=450>
        <asp:Label ID="kalanameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("kalaname") %>'/>
         <asp:Label ID="kaladetailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("kaladetail") %>'/>
            <br />
        </td>
        <td width=100>
         <asp:Label ID="kalapriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("kalaprice") %>' ForeColor=Green />
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='تومان' />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td>
         <asp:Label ID="numLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("num") %>'  />
         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='عدد' />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID='<%# Eval("num") %>'  runat="server" cssclass=btnd  OnClick="delete_kala"  />
        <%--    <img src="images/delete.png" width="20" height=20 /> --%>
            <br> </br></td>

        <td>
         <asp:Button ID="ed" runat="server" cssclass=btne  OnClick="edit_kala"/>
           <%-- <img src="images/edit.png" width=20 height=20 /> --%>
            <br> </br></td>
        </tr>
        </table>





        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:onlineshopConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="    

 SELECT userid, kalaidbuy, num,kalaname,kaladetail,kalaprice
```

FROM cart inner join kala on 
 cart.kalaidbuy=kala.kalaID
            where userid=@d  "

```
        >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="d" QueryStringField="UID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The problem is that this button is going to be available at server-side, so you *have* to know the ID at compile-time. This is because a field will be generated that corresponds to the button. That field needs a name, and it uses the ID.

Comment: Can you post what you are trying to achieve, as there may well be a better way of doing this - adding a custom attribute, or a class, or similar.